# how to set logo for root window in tkinter python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, png, gif, ico

In the code below I am trying to set the logo for root window.
I tried .ico, .gif and .png file formats.
In case of .gif and .png images, logo appears only in taskbar but not on the root window.
And when I try .ico image, there is an error: tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "icon.ico".
I tried several methods but not a single one of them worked for me, out of which two methods are shown in code below.
Are there any specification for the logo images like image size, resolution, dimensions etc..
In case if it matters I am using linux machine.
CODE:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x400')

# First method
root.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, PhotoImage(file="icon.ico"))

# Second method
root.iconbitmap(r'icon.png')

root.mainloop()
```

## 3rd method:

```
root.iconbitmap(r'icon.ico')
```

Comment: Where exactly on the root window do you want to show the image? What system are you using?

Comment: I want the logo to be appeared beside the root title, and I am using linux machine

Comment: If you haven't an `icon.ico` file you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63324528)

Comment: @ Atlas435, I do have icon.ico, but there is an error which I mentioned above.
And sorry to say but none of the methods from the link you shared are working for me.

Comment: when I tried `root.iconbitmap('icon.ico')`, there is an error: tkinter.TclError: bitmap "icon.ico" not defined

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that Linuxes did that. I though it was only a Windows or Mac thing. My Ubuntu doesn't do it, anyway.

Comment: Is your `icon.ico` in the same directory as your `script_name.py` that you currently running with this code?

Comment: @ Sylvester Kruin, I am using Ubuntu 20.04.
And I tried dozens of methods but no luck.

Comment: @ Atlas435, I tried both the methods, I put icon.ico in the same directory as my main.py and in another I put it in Icons folder. But both the methods didn't work for me

Comment: @MilindKhobragade did you see [these answers here?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45361749/13629335)

Comment: @Atlas435, methods from the above link are also not working for me.
Such a simple thing but its taking way too much time to resolve.
I don't understand what's wrong

Comment: @MilindKhobragade did you just renamed your image with `.ico` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238955/discussion-between-milind-khobragade-and-atlas435).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use raw strings.
Make sure it's a legit .ico file and it's in the same directory as your python file. Then you can move it (.iconbitmap method) beneath your root window definition.

```
root.iconbitmap('filename.ico')
```

If it doesn't work let me know. It might be your setup or an OS specific error . We'll try other ways.

Comment: Try using an absolute path if it'll work as well

Comment: If those don't work, try converting the image to an **xbm** file and add it to your path with an @ prefix.

Comment: @ Emmanuel Oloyede, I tried `root.iconbitmap('filename.ico')`, tried with absolute path, tried xbm with @ prefix. Nothing worked for me. I am using vscode on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: @MilindKhobragade pls share a picture of the source code and error message.

Comment: I've added the code at the end of my question as `3rd method`. And the Error: `_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "icon.png" not defined`.

Comment: Okay, I'd like to go on a free session with you but it wouldn't be beneficial to those who encounter the same problem here. So, check all the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18537918/why-isnt-ico-file-defined-when-setting-windows-icon. It should help.

Comment: I tried every option available on the link you shared. sorry to say but none worked for me.

Comment: I don't know what the free session is, but pls lets do it. I'll post every solution you give me.

Comment: Okay, sorry this is coming late. Chat me up on IG @tech_emmy (https://www.instagram.com/tech_emmy/)

Comment: sorry but I am not on IG. Can't we do that here on stackoverflow?

Comment: The thing is, I want to be able to see your code and output directly. And then I'll try debugging it.

Comment: @ Emmanuel Oloyede, I don't know what to do now. Pls suggest something.

Comment: Okay, Make sure you set up VSCode share feature. We'll use that. Are you on any social platform?

Comment: @ Emmanuel Oloyede, I am on twitter

Comment: Okay, chat me up on Twitter @tech_emmyy

Comment: @ Emmanuel Oloyede, your direct message service is off. Please start the service so that we can chat

Comment: The service for message requests is now on